# How to set a button at the beginning of each line of my table?

Tags: html, postgresql, php-pgsql

I try to have a button at the beginning of each line. I will use this button to open a line on a pop up windows.

I know it is not hard to do but somehow I am struggling to place the button at the beginning of a line.

To give you the context of my code. I generate my table after an `SQL` query, so I don't know how many lines I will have.
Here is the code :

```
$result = Db::query($requete);

$texte = "<table class='table table-bordered table-sm'><thead>$table_header</thead>";
$texte .= "<tbody>";

if (!pg_num_rows($result)){
    $nb_ligne = "Aucune ligne trouvée !";
}else{
    $nb_ligne ="Nombre de lignes : ".pg_num_rows($result);
}
while($row = pg_fetch_row($result)){
    $texte .= "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $value){
        $texte .= "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' onclick=''></button></td><td style='word-break: keep-all'>$value</td>";
    }
    $texte .= "</tr>";
}
$texte .= "</tbody></table>";

$response = new Response();
$response->assign('nb_ligne', 'innerHTML', $nb_ligne);
$response->assign('tableau_resultat', 'innerHTML', $texte);

return $response;
```

I first create the header of my table. `$table_header` contains `<th>` tags and header value. Then I loop on each line of the dataset returned by my query. For each line, I create `<tr>` tag and for each value I create `<td>` tag. I use `Jaxon` (PHP lib to do AJAX) to display my table.

I tried to put a button at the beginning but they are displayed before my table.

I get this ouput :
[image: img]

The buttons are the blue boxes on the left above headers. 
I want them to be on the left of each lines apart from header line.

I want to learn from this, so, if possible, explain to me what I'm doing wrong here, or if my approach is lacking insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the buttons only once per row - why are you creating a button for each column ?!

```
while($row = pg_fetch_row($result)){
    $texte .= "<tr><td><button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' onclick=''></button></td>";
    foreach ($row as $value){
        $texte .= "<td style='word-break: keep-all'>$value</td>";
    }
    $texte .= "</tr>";
}
```

You should also put an empty cell on the left of your header.

Comment: Works as expected ! Thank you

Well I tried what you wrote but I did not put `<button>` in a `<td>` and I was not the outplay expected.